# Como eliminar columna de Excel con Apache Poi y java

Tags: java, apache-poi

He eliminado filas con el siguiente método `sheet.removeRow(sheet.getRow(0));` sin embargo quiero eliminar una columna mas no conozco el método, alguien me puede ayudar se los agradecería..

Comment: Este es el ejemplo de un método, espero les sirva.. https://stackrverflow.com/questions/1180110/apache-poi-xls-column-remove

Comment: Lograste ya resolver el problema?

Comment: Si Raul, en la respuesta debajo se encuentra el link del método que me ayudo!!

Comment: Te sugiero agregues la respuesta en base a [answer] para que sea de ayuda a la comunidad.